# How to display the content of third or more level nested panel in expansion panel using angular life cycle hooks

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular5

I am wrapping the angular material expansion panel component in angular 5. It is working fine with first and second level panels i.e.,nested panel, the content inside the second level nested panel is rendering using angular life cycle hook AfterViewInit. First level content is rendering using OnInit. I am using ngTemplateOutlet to render the template as the panel content.

But I am facing a issue with third level nested panel content rendering, it is not rendering the content of the third or even more levels of nested panels. I tried with AfterContentInit, but not working.

stackblitz link [expansion-panel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye5dxw).

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have to wait for anything before you can render the component?

Comment: Actually I am trying to make my component as reusable. So angular material expansion panel supports any number of nested panels. In my component, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have added the `MultiplenestedPanel` templates inside your nested `<expansion>` components, so the parent `<my-app>` component is no longer able to see them. Move the templates outside the main DOM structure of `<my-app>` so they can be accessed by `AppComponent`:

```
<expansion [panels]="panelSettings.panels">
    <ng-template #nestedPanels>
        <expansion [panels]="nestedPanelSettings.panels">
            <ng-template #nestedPanelIntegrity>
                <p>
                    We build trust through making and keeping commitments.
                </p>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #nestedPanelAgility>
                <p>
                    We act quickly, decisively and pursue the fastest course to accurate solutions. We take calculated risks.
                </p>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #nestedPanelInnovation>
                <!--<p>
                    We constantly stretch ourselves to efficiently achieve the best results. Our curiosity leads us to solve problems.
                </p>-->
                <expansion [panels]="multiplePanelSettings.panels">
                </expansion>
            </ng-template>
        </expansion>
    </ng-template>
</expansion>

<ng-template #MultiplenestedPanel>
    <p>
        Third level nestedPanel1
    </p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #MultiplenestedPanel1>
    <p>
        Third level nestedPanel2
    </p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working fine as your suggestion.